# A file on my repo containing git pushed date and time

Tags: git, jekyll, github-pages

I want to update a file with date and time when I git push to my website running on github pages, with jekyll. Although it put me into commit loop, I managed to do this with a `pre-commit` git hook script. I was wondering if there is a healthier way to do this maybe using jekyll or something else? I'm using Github Desktop for pushing.

**Edit** : I solved the problem by adding the `git add my_file` command to the last line of my `pre-commit` hook and the hook worked as expected, first updating the file and then instantly committing without waiting for the next commit.

Comment: Could you please define "healthier" here? *(Hooks are fine.)*

Comment: A better solution, in my opinion, would be to not change your files on commit but instead bake this part into your deployment script. ie. the deployment script would grab metadata from git, such as commit hash and date, and bake that into the files that are being deployed